# Show Tags of Custom Post Type outside of Loop

Tags: array, tags

I have a custom function that someone else here help me build that shows custom post types on my front page.  I want to add the tags/tag-links of each post to it, but whenever I reference `get_the_tags()` it just says Array.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_portfolio_cases($atts = null, $content = null, $tag = null) {

$odd = TRUE;
$out = '';

$args = array( 
    'numberposts' => '-1', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio_cases',
);

$recent = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

if ( $recent ) {

        $out .= '<div id="portfolio-cases" class="row">';

        $posttags = get_the_tags($item['ID']);

        foreach ( $recent as $item ) {


            if ( $odd == TRUE ) {
                $out .= '<div class="case_img col-sm-12 col-md-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="';
                $out .= get_field('laptop_image',$item['ID']);
                $out .= '" /></div><div class="case_text col-sm-12 col-md-6"><h5>';
                $out .= get_the_title($item['ID']);
                $out .= '</h5><p class="case_tags">';
                if($posttags) {
                    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                        $out .= $tag->name . ' ';
                    }
                }
                $out .= '</p><p>';
                $out .= get_field('project_text',$item['ID']);
                $out .= '</p>';
                $out .= '<a class="btn btn-front understrap-read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">VIEW WORK</a></p>';
                $out .= '</div>';
                $odd = FALSE;
            } else {
                $out .= '<div class="case_img col-sm-12 col-md-6 push-md-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="';
                $out .= get_field('laptop_image',$item['ID']);
                $out .= '" /></div><div class="case_text col-sm-12 col-md-6 pull-md-6"><h5>';
                $out .= get_the_title($item['ID']);
                $out .= '</h5><p class="case_tags">';
                if($posttags) {
                    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                        $out .= $tag->name . ' ';
                    }
                }
                $out .= '</p><p>';
                $out .= get_field('project_text',$item['ID']);
                $out .= '</p>';
                $out .= '<a class="btn btn-front understrap-read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">VIEW WORK</a></p>';
                $out .= '</div>';
                $odd = TRUE;
            }
        }

        $out .= '</div>';
    }

    if ( $tag ) {
        return $out;
    } else {
        echo $out;
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'recentposts', 'custom_recent_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing order:

```
foreach ( $recent as $item ) {
    $posttags = get_the_tags($item['ID']);
```

Comment: reversing the order makes the entries/posts disappear entirely.  Where as the original just prevents the tags from showing up.

Comment: Original version doesn't make sense, because you are trying to use the `$item` variable before it is assigned within the loop - and that's why you get the error about the array. The rest of the code looks reasonable and generates code when tested, although if your callback function in `add_shortcode` is called `custom_recent_posts` your function should be have the same name and not `custom_portfolio_cases`.